# How do I find the direction of current with Flemming's left hand rule?

Tags: electromagnetism

How am I supposed to know what is the direction of flow of current when the diagram shows me that the current is flowing in all directions?

[image: flow of current in a dc motor]

This might sound stupid but I think that whenever there  is a repulsion, meaning 2 north poles near each other, the current moves downwards while current moves upwards fpr southpole deflection. Correct me if I'm wrong, and in the case of attraction, current moves upwards for north pole of the em field and downwards for the southpole of the em field.o

Answer (score 1):

I am going to answer by encouraging you to use your right hand rather than your left hand. The reason is that to do all of physics and mathematics it is sufficient to only use right hand rules. Introducing left hand rules then just leads to confusion.

To use the right hand rule, proceed as follows.

First you need to know that outside the pole piece the magnetic field lines run from the north to the south pole. So this tells you the direction of the magnetic field $\bf B$.

I am assuming your diagram shows a motor not a generator. In this case the battery makes some current flow, and as a result there is a force on the wire.

The force on the wire (called electromotive force) pushes the charged particles that are in the wire. The direction of this force is given by a formula which employs a type of mathematical operation called vector product, but I am assuming you have not met that so I will not use it. The basic idea is that three things determine the force: the charge $q$ on the particle in question, its velocity $\bf v$, and the magnetic field $\bf B$. To get the direction of the force, first hold your right hand flat and make the fingers of your right hand point along the velocity. For the hoop in your diagram, this velocity is in the direction of the electron motion around the hoop.

The next step is to bend or curl your right hand so that the fingers swing from the direction of $\bf v$ to the direction of $\bf B$, and keep holding your hand still. When you have done this, your right thumb will be pointing in the direction of the force if the particles have positive charge, and the opposite direction if the particles have negative charge.

For example, let's examine the left part of the hoop in your diagram. The velocity is into the page and the magnetic field runs from left to right, so with my right hand with fingers curling from in to right I find my thumb pointing downwards. But electrons have negative charge so I find the force on them is upwards in this part of the wire. That makes the wire rotate as shown.

Answer (score 0):

So in general the magnetic field goes from south to north so if you point your left index finger the the direction of that field you the point the current with you second fingue perpendicular to the index you can test the wires separately so ome going forward and one going back. The you see the direction of the forces so one part is pushed up the other pushed down so then we get rotation around the center